# Can wounds be treated in Adventure mode?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

Upon looking at my status in adventure mode, I see that my right hand "needs setting".  Is there a way other than simply time/rest to deal with this, or do actual doctors exist?

Comment: In the previous version it wasn't possible. Sadly I have not played adventure mode yet in the newest version.

Comment: Maybe you can 1) retire your adventurer, 2) start a new game in Fortress mode, 3) set up a fortress near where you retired the adventurer, 4) build a hospital in it, 5) treat the adventurer, 6) retire/abandon the fortress, 7) start a game in Adventurer mode and play as the treated adventurer again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't receive medical attention in adventure mode. You can fully regenerate by turning into a werebeast and back, which happens every full moon if you are infected by a werebeast's attacks. The next best thing to do is to wait (doing so by traveling on the world map is easiest). It is a good idea to skinny dip after getting injured to prevent infections, preferably in running or at least not stagnant water..